# How can I open FilePicker services authentication in new window

Tags: javascript, filepicker.io

Using the [Filepicker](http://filepicker.io) services, I open the dialog in the new window for the user. (A child window.). However when you try and authenticate with a service(dropbox,facebook etc), it opens the oauth dialog in the parent window.

How can I open the oauth dialog in a new window or how can I return focus on the child window after the authentication is done?

I have tried doing a focus method on the child but that doesn't work due to security issues with browsers. And there's no way to open the link since the filepicker itself is an Iframe.

Is there a setting I can adjust on Filepicker for this?